# Does IMDB provide IMDBID for the movies in their data(plain text files)?

Tags: api, imdb

For IMDB, I am interested in only retrieving ID. If they are not providing ID in their database, this database might not be useful to me. Please tell me if they provide ID in their data.

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that the imdbIDs are not provided in the plain text data files or in any other downloadable format (not for free, at least).

Being the author of IMDbPY, I'm pretty sure of this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the data files, you could use http://imdbapi.org/, which does supply the ID.